# Time Series (White Noise) Question

Tags: time-series, white-noise

Suppose {$W_t$} and {$Y_t$} are two independent normal white noise series with $Var(W_t)=2Var(Y_t)=4$. Let $X_t = W_t-0.5W_{t-1}$ and $Z_t=Y_t+0.4Y_{t-1}-0.4Y_{t-2}$. Put $V_t=X_t-Z_t$. Find the $Cov(V_t,V_{t-k})$, $k=0,1,2,3,..$

So I tried doing this:

$Cov(V_t,V_{t-1})$=$E[(W_t-0.5W_{t-1}-Y_t-0.4Y_{t-1}+0.4Y_{t-2})(W_{t-1}-0.5W_{t-2}-Y_{t-1}-0.4Y_{t-2}+0.4Y_{t-3})]$

- k is time lag

For k=0, $Cov(V_t,V_{t-k})$=1

For k=1, $Cov(V_t,V_{t-k})$=-4.8

For k=2, $Cov(V_t,V_{t-k})$=-0.8

For k>2, $Cov(V_t,V_{t-k})$=0

Is this correct? Any help/contribution will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is $k$? It does not appear anywhere else.

Comment: Oh yes sorry I forgot to mention. k is suppose to be the time lag.

Comment: That would suggest that you need to replace all occurrences of "$V_{t-1}$" by "$V_{t-k}$."

Comment: Could you perhaps write out the calculations you used to find one of these covariances? I cannot see how you could possibly get $1$ as the answer when $k=0$, so it would be good to see the details.

Comment: So when $k=0$ I got $Var[(W_t-0.5W_{t-1}-Y_t-0.4Y_{t-1}+0.4Y_{t-2})=4-0.5^2(4)-2-0.4^2(2)+0.4^2(2)=1$

Comment: @user3350759 Variance rarely _subtract_ the way you have them: if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ have the _same_ variance.  Your answer for $k=0$ is incorrect, and there is no reason to believe that your other calculations will be correct.

Comment: Then could someone tell me how to calculate?